# Using Sudo in Yeoman/Grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, yeoman

I'm trying to automate creating virtual host files on my mac in yeoman/grunt. After yeoman gets the file all tidy I call

```
grunt.file.write('/etc/apache2/virtualhosts/' + fileName, tidyFileContents);
```

But this doesn't work because I need permissions to move anything around in the etc/apache2/virtualhosts/ dir. I've thought about doing

```
grunt.file.write(fileName, tidyFileContents);
```

then follow up with a:

```
sudo mv fileName /etc/apache2/virtualhosts
```

but I don't know how to write that code in javascript. My question is how can I write the above code ^ in yeoman syntax to get the desired result. Or what are some other ways I can sudo a file into a permissions virtualhost dir. My only constraint is that I cannot take the permissions off the virtualhosts dir. Thanks for your help ahead of time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is independent of yeoman, you can use [process exec](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) and execute any shell command.

Comment: Thanks mate, I knew this was possible in C. Had no idea this was available in javascript. Changed my day today haha